# Use of for next loop to introduce blanks at random in large matrix, R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, random, na

I have a large matrix, n x m, where m - no. of columns, dataset is called data.  In reality, ncol could range from 80 to 200 columns.

I want to introduce random missing cell values, say 1% in each of the columns, using

```
res<-do.call(cbind,lapply(lapply(data[,1:ncol(data)],function(x) data.frame(x)),function(x) x[sample(1:nrow(x),0.01*nrow(x)),]))
```

Missing cells will contain NA, using

```
data[,1][data[,1]%in%res[,1]]<- NA
```

Where [,1] is column 1. If the no. of columns [ncol] is 5, I can do manually, by changing the number in the equation above each time.  This gets very time consuming if say there are 50 columns.  If 200 or more columns....

I tried using a for/next loop i.e.

```
ncol(data)  
n = length(ncol(data))

for (i in 1:n)

{

  data[,i][data[,i]%in%res[,i]]<- NA
  
}
```

But this didn't work - no random NAs were inserted.

My questions -

[1] how do I generate random NAs in an n x m matrix, at 0.1%, 1%, and 5%, using for/next loops?

[2] I have no doubt there is a more efficient way to do this, but I have had no luck so far.  What would be the best method?

[3] If I take the manual approach, the columns contents are changed as required.  Is there a way to save the changed [i.e. now containing random NAs] n x m matrix?

Comment: ```n = length(ncol(data))``` will always return 1 since ncol(data) already counts the columns and returns an integer. ```length()``` then gets this integer and return 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ktiu already provided an answer, but to clarify why your code doesn't work and how to fix it and address your question (1):

```
n <- ncol(data)

for(i in 1:n){
random_rows <- sample(1:nrow(data), 0.01*nrow(data))
data[random_rows, i] <- NA
}
```

Note that 1) `ncol(data)` already gives you the number of columns.
Now you can go through all the columns using the `for` loop and in each column, you generate a random sample of row indices. Then simply set those rows in column `i` to NA.

Using `apply` is much faster than using a loop, however it is not as intuitive for beginners.

Question (3) depends on how you want to save the matrix. There are many ways to save data in R, e.g. you can save them as [RDA or RDATA](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/saving-data-into-r-data-format-rds-and-rdata), or you can [export them as csv](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AlphaPart/versions/0.8.1/topics/write.csv) file or even [as Excel file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.5/topics/write.xlsx). (Note that this requires the respective package to be installed and loaded.)

Regarding your comment, I think this should work:

```
n <- ncol(data)

for(i in 1:n){
random_number <- runif(1, min = 0.001, max = 0.05)
random_rows <- sample(1:nrow(data), round(random_number*nrow(data), digits = 0))
data[random_rows, i] <- NA
}
```

Here, we just generate a random number between 0.001 and 0.05 and use this number as the share of `NA` values for this column. I wrapped the calculation (share * number of rows) in `round()` to make sure the resulting number is an integer (the `sample()` function also accepts non-integer values for the number of samples to choose but in this case it will always round down, never up, which makes the 5% less likely than the other possible values, I guess).

Comment: Hi Manuel, this was extremely insightful and helpful, thank you.   If I can take this to the next level - if there are n columns, how can I introduce NAs to each column to varying degrees?  In other words, each column can contain different numbers of NAs, between 0.1 and 5% , generated randomly.

Comment: I added a solution to my answer. Basically, you just replace the 0.01 in the code by a random number between 0.001 and 0.05, which can be generated using ```runif()```.

Comment: Thank you Manual, I was some way from arriving at your solution.  Practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this approach speaks to some of your questions:

Taking a large matrix with 100 columns with 200 values each

```
data <- matrix(runif(20000), ncol = 100)
```

you could do

```
apply(data, 2, \(c) {
   na_positions <- sample(1:length(c), 0.01 * length(c))
   c[na_positions] <- NA
   return(c)
}) -> data_with_na
```

Verifying the result for the first four columns:

```
summary(data_with_na[, 1:4])
```

```
       V1                 V2                  V3                 V4         
 Min.   :0.004131   Min.   :0.0009613   Min.   :0.004394   Min.   :0.00178  
 1st Qu.:0.246076   1st Qu.:0.2334719   1st Qu.:0.224328   1st Qu.:0.20329  
 Median :0.499454   Median :0.4686971   Median :0.458352   Median :0.49704  
 Mean   :0.501149   Mean   :0.4868858   Mean   :0.482523   Mean   :0.48674  
 3rd Qu.:0.767258   3rd Qu.:0.7511260   3rd Qu.:0.756019   3rd Qu.:0.72742  
 Max.   :0.997355   Max.   :0.9889819   Max.   :0.993775   Max.   :0.99797  
 NA's   :2          NA's   :2           NA's   :2          NA's   :2
```

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your expertise, much appreciated.  I note the comment re beginners, very diplomatic :-).  ktiu - I am unable to get your approach to work, the following error is returned -> apply(data, 2, \(c) {
Error: unexpected input in "apply(data, 2, \"
>   na_positions <- sample(1:length(c), 0.01 * length(c))
>   c[na_positions] <- NA
Error in c[na_positions] <- NA : 
  object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
>   return(c)
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> }) -> data_with_na
Error: unexpected '}' in "}".   Could you point out why pls?   thx.

Comment: You're not using the most recent version of R (4.1). You can upgrade or replace the first line with `apply(data, 2, function(c) {`